# Migrate TFS2010 to TFS2015 including Sharepoint migration

Tags: tfs-2015

I would like to create a new TFS 2015 server that is a copy of the old TFS 2010  machine for testing TFS 2015.
Our current TFS 2010 has both Sharepoint and Reporting Services.

I can't seem to find any good guides on how to migrate TFS 2010 to TFS 2015 without taking the old server offline that also includes Sharepoint migration.

This guide talks about TFS 2010 to 2015 but does not include Sharepoint.
https://intovsts.net/2015/07/09/upgrading-tfs-2010-sp1-to-tfs-2015-rc2/

This page says something about changing server ID if I want to keep the old server online. Which I do want to keep the old server online.
[Migrate TFS2010 to TFS2013 on new hardware keeping existing TFS2010 installation in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572139/migrate-tfs2010-to-tfs2013-on-new-hardware-keeping-existing-tfs2010-installation)

The Microsoft guide does not even talk about Sharepoint.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/upgrade-tfs/get-started

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to upgrade your SharePoint instance first. TFS 2010 supported `Office SharePoint Server 2007 (Standard, Enterprise)` and `Windows SharePoint Services 3.0`. TFS 2015 supports `SharePoint 2010 and 2013 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)`. After upgrading your SharePoint instance, you'll need to install TFS 2015 on it and configure SharePoint Extensions.

Comment: I want both the old TFS 2010 which has Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 on it and the new TFS 2015 which will have SharePoint 2013 on it, to run at the same time. Basically we want a new server with TFS 2015 and new SharePoint that has that same data as the old 2010 so that we can test and not move everyone to the new box just yet.

Comment: You can follow this article to move your team project collections from old server to new server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936138(v=vs.120).aspx.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not trying to move the SharePoint just yet. I want to setup a new server and test that server while the old server is still in use. This article does not talk about the client issues where two servers running at the same time causes the VS clients to see both servers (which is bad because we are only testing the new server).